# The term 'release-cli' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am learning about CI/CD with the goal in mind to optimize the development.

At work we use Windows 11 machines and we have our own Gitlab server (we dont use Public Gitlab).

After downloading Gitlab runner, I have followed the simple instructions to start the runner that were provided under Gitlab Repository -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners

My runner config:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Runner for ESP32 test application"
  url = "https://xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxx.lt/"
  id = 5
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-12-11T09:30:58Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "pwsh"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
```

After I have created a runner, I have created a .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - release


release_job:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG                 # Run this job when a tag is created
  script:
    - echo "running release_job"
  release:                               # See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#release for available properties
    tag_name: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    description: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: My bad. Sorted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using Shell (pwsh) executor...

You are using a shell executor, moreover on Windows. The pipeline is written for docker container `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest`. Use docker executor.

Comment: I have initially thought about this idea. But I have read somewhere that using docker on Windows is not recommended. 

We have access to Ubuntu virtual machine that we can access using SSH. I can install docker there but I am not too sure how can I tell my runner to execute docker not from my PC but from virtual machine instead. Perhaps you got any tips?

Comment: Edit:
I should probabaly create a seperate post regarding the docker issue I have as this is might not be very relevant. Anyways, thanks for finding the issue. Apparently this pipeline is not intended to use with shell

Comment: `how can I tell my runner to execute docker not from my PC but from virtual machine instead` Install gitlab-runner on the virtual machine.

Comment: Thats quite obvious! I dont know why I thought creating a runner from my PC was gonna work.. I have installed runner on the VM and created runner via VM and was able to run the job without any issue. Thanks for clarifying